# Create csv(s) from xlsx

Tags: excel, csv, converters, file-extension

How can I bulk convert excel files (xlsx) to csv? I tried

```
$source = 'C:\path\to\file'

Get-ChildItem $source '*.xlsx' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.xlsx','.csv' }
```

but the csvs were unreadable. Ideally, I'd like to be able to make a csv from each sheet (so I don't have to separate them manually before converting).

Thanks.

Comment: You can't just rename the file and expect that to change the file contents. You need a program or module that understands XLSX and can then generate a CSV based on the contents. That's too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @mason I looked into what you said and I did some research.. I found/got a working function below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found/got:

```
$source = 'C:\path\to\file'

Function ExcelCSV ($File)
{
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $false
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName)
    foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets)
        {
        $ws.SaveAs(($Files.FullName -replace ".xlsx$","") + ".csv", 6)
        }
        $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Close()
        $Excel.Quit()
}

Foreach ($Files in (Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter "*.xlsx"))
{
    ExcelCSV($Files)
}
```